# Popup Window with javascript - open new popup in the old popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

A snipet:-

```
     // listen for clicks, opens a hyperlink attached to the event. //
                 $("#canvas").click(function popMessage(e) {
                     $("#canvas").hide();
                     // hyperlink opens a new window upon click on the bubble
                     return !window.open('About.aspx?info=' + info, "pop", "resizable,width=1000,height=600,");
                 });
```

This works good.

However, I am thinking of a scenario, where a person opens 10 different pop up windows and gets confused which window was referencing to which click.

Came to mind that I could, only allow one pop up window at a time.

for the first click, a new popup window opens.
for every next click, the old popup window is replaced by the new click.

finally when parent page is closed, popup window is closed.

What kind of property should I be looking at for this concept?

( to be noted that the address of my target popup is not the same, every time, a small part of the address is a code passed as the 'info' )

Comment: Why are you hiding #canvas? If it is hidden they won't be able to click it again!?

Comment: its a canvas on a canvas. haha. so the original underlying image is still there. a dream within a dream. blah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you just want to close the old window each time #canvas is clicked?

```
//earlier:
var winPop = false;
// in the click event:

if (winPop) {
    winPop.close();
}
winPop = window.open('About.aspx?info=' + info, "pop", 
    "resizable,width=1000,height=600,");
```

And to close it later:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if (winPop) {
        winPop.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: theoretically I was thinking of this approach, but winPop is defined after the check statement.  so winPop is initially undefined. Is it safe to initialize it an empty value?

Comment: It doesn't need to be initialised - this is JavaScript ;). If it doesn't already exist, then winPop is 'undefined', which is equivalent to 'false' in the if statement.

Comment: Are you running this in an ancient IE? Anyways, outside of the event (globally) you could add 'var winPop = false;'. Notice I didn't use 'var' in my code, so that winPop is global and available to the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: yeah i ended up assigning it the var winPop = false..haha, I am using IE 9.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I always declare my variables, but neglected to in my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I know you request a different answer but maybe this can be a second approach for solve your problem and also try to avoid the "pop up blocker from the browsers" and confuse the user. My two cents

Is a basic example to make a modal pop up using an iframe. http://jsfiddle.net/G8Cnh/

HTML

```
<div class="popup" style='display:none'>
    <i>X</i>
    <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" border="0" src="http://jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">open</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(){
 $(".popup").fadeToggle();
});

$(document).on("click","i",function(){
 $(".popup").fadeOut();
});
```

CSS

```
.popup{
    width:470px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-225px;    
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-225px;
    height:54%;
    background:#F60;    
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    opacity:.8;
    padding:10px;    
}

.popup i{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    left:100%;
    width:15px;
    hegith:15px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.popup i:hover{
    background:#F60;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: if you want a more professional approach you could use this http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ best

Comment: Just got around implementing the method suggested by you:-
http://jsfiddle.net/My9NZ/2/

The functionalities work, however the css styling doesn't work for the <i>X</i> element. Any advice?

Comment: do you need the X run on the server, or just hide the popup?

Comment: I want it to just run on the side panel...aka 'popup'. It's my closing the side-panel/popup element. The function of closing it works.. with toggle(), however the css styling, such as i hover{} doesn't work. Its not a necessity, but pretty cool to have working.

Comment: solved it, I just had to use a div class around the <i> X </i>.
but what if I wanted to use the div class name "popup" to use the fade out effect. can that be done?

$(document).on("click","popup",function(){
 $(".popup").fadeOut();
});